# OPENCV convolution for big kernels with size nearly equal to image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, signal-processing, fft, ifft

My image is of size 107x149. And my filter kernel is of size 75x75. What is the best way(in terms of speed) to convolve the image with kernel? Note : filters are non-separable.

Answer (score 2):

Generic `cv::filter2D` is good enough for such case. It uses DFT-based algorithm for sufficiently large kernels.

Comment: used filter2D but it's still slow. Any other ideas?(Apart from GPU, CUDA programming?)

Comment: I am using ARM processor. I think it doesn't support IPP.